# How to animate div height smoothly automatically [without using animate() everytime]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I know the jQuery `animate` function, and I can change the divs height with that smoothly, but the question is:

I have a div:

```
<div class="blah">Content with 3 lines</div>
```

And then I append some more lines to the above div using jQuery, the div height is `auto` so it's gonna go longer, but not smoothly, is there anyway it could go longer smoothly like using jQuery `animate` function?

**I just don't want to type animate({blah}) on any appends, ajax calls, etc..**

***Is it possible to have a function to get called on every divs `height changes`? and deal with it using `animate` function?***

I have also read about transitions, so I did:

```
.blah{
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: height 1s ease-in-out !important;
    -ms-transition: height 1s ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: height 1s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out !important;
}
```

but not working

The jQuery method, which appends data:

```
$('blah').append('<p style="clear:both;">Another Line</p>')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Transitions will only work on direct changes to the `height` attribute. In my opinion the only way to archive this, is to create a hidden (not `display: none` though - use `left: -100000px`) "shadow" `div` where you put the text into, determine the height afterwards, then update the actual `div` with both text and the determined height value. Note that the shadow `div` needs a defined `width`.

Comment: @try-catch-finally can you come with a jsfiddle? ty

Comment: Well, actually [not](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf9Rh/)

Answer (score 1):

Transitions will only work on direct changes to the `height` attribute.

In my opinion the only way to archive this, is to create a hidden "shadow" `div` where you put the text into, determine the height afterwards, then update the actual `div` with both text and the determined `height` value.

Note that the shadow div needs a defined width and do not use `display: none` as it would prevent the browser from calculating the dimension - use `left: -100000px`.

I hope, this is what you were asking for: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf9Rh/)

And no: doing this automatically (event-like) does not work, but you could move this code easily into a wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.blah').append('<p style="clear:both; display:none" id='new_div'>Another Line</p>');
$('#new_div').fadeIn();
```

You can even wrap this in a function like:

```
function appendAnin(parent,childId){
  $(parent).append('<p style="clear:both; display:none" id='"+child+"'>Another Line</p>');
  $("#"+childId).fadeIn();
}
```

and then call the function:

```
appendAnim(".blah","new_div");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using invalid selector `$('blah')`, should be `$('.blah')` and you wanted to show it smoothly so you need to hide this first then show or animate:

Example:

```
$('.blah').append('<p style="clear:both;">Another Line</p>').hide().show('slow');
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wfhk/)

Comment: what it has to do with my question? add a button, add data by append and see it's not gonna go longer smoothly

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/zwvNY/1935/)**</kbd>

jQuery

```
$("#blah")
    .hide()
    .html('<p>Another Line</p><p>Another Line</p><p>Another Line</p>')
    .slideDown('slow');
```

CSS

```
div {
    background:slategray;
    color:white;
    padding:20px;
}
```